# xcode 7 ios9 no provisioning profile found

Tags: xcode, ios9, xcode7

As pe the apple doc [Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/LaunchingYourApponDevices/LaunchingYourApponDevices.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH27-SW3) provisioning profile is not required for connected devices. But in my xcode it is still asking for provisioning profile.

i am using a project created with cordova

Comment: @Uma can you be more specific ?  i am new to xcode

Comment: Hi are you working with Xcode only ah??

Comment: yes i am using xcode 7 , for packaging a cordova hybrid app.

Comment: have u added developer account ?

Comment: yes i have a developer account but  i don't have valid dev certificate. As per documentation nothing is required for running an app from xcode 7 in ios9 devices